# How to use Groovy Set for unique elements?

Tags: groovy

As simple as this must be I still can't understand where am I wrong:

```
class A {
    boolean equals(o) { true }
}
def s = [new A(), new A()] as Set
assert s.size() == 1 // Assertion failed: actually gives 2
```

Which method should I override in order to get uniqueness?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[hashCode](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273.html), as you would with Java

```
class A {
    boolean equals(o) { true }
    int hashCode() { 1 }
}
def s = [new A(), new A()] as Set
assert s.size() == 1
```